# How To Use Spree Route Helpers in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, rspec3

I am trying to use the Spree 2.3 route helpers in Rspec 3.0. In the main app, I can access them by prefixing `spree.`, like so:

```
spree.admin_login_path => 'spree/admin/user_sessions#new'
```

However I can't seem to access them in Rspec.

```
#rspec error
undefined local variable or method `spree_admin_login_path'
```

I've found reference to including the helpers in the rails_helper file, but **this throws an error**

```
# app/spec/rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Spree::Core::UrlHelpers
end

# configuring the above results in the following
app/spec/rails_helper.rb:21:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Spree (NameError)
```

How do I access the spree routes given in `$ rake routes` in my tests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging through the Spree code I was able to put together this setup for my rails_helper file that lets me use spree routes such as `spree.admin_login_path` in my spec files:

```
# app/spec/rails_helper.rb
require 'spree/testing_support/url_helpers'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Spree::TestingSupport::UrlHelpers
end
```

I'm sure there's a smoother way to include all of Spree's test helpers, and I'd love to hear about it from someone who knows.